# How to find relevant fields from a document text?

Tags: java, nlp, text-processing

I have extracted text from a pdf of bills , it appears something like this ( bills may differ)

```
___________________________________________________
|invoiceNo  | itemId |  item_name  |   qty | amount |
|___________|________|_____________|_______|________|
|12323133   |  1     |  Hp laptops |    1  |  180000|
|1234534H   |  1     |  Hp laptops |    1  |  180000|
|SW323133   |  1     |  Hp laptops |    1  |  180000|
|FGF323133  |  1     |  Hp laptops |    1  |  180000|
|___________|________|_____________|_______|________|
```

Now , I need an algorithm to find all the relevant information like invoice numbers/item_name etc. The text can be short or longer than 2-3 pages

Comment: Does the text have any formatting, like CSV or similar? Can you show us an example? What have you tried so far in java?

Comment: Is your source file a pdf?

Comment: Yea ,  it's the  text extracted from pdf/image using pdftools.

Comment: What format or data structure is it after extraction? Any `List<String>` of lines or maybe a `Map<Integer, String>` of lines with their number?

Comment: I would suggest when you are extracting data using pdftools convert this data into jsonobject. Once you got the data in jsonobject you will have more control over your data. Otherwise in a text format to handle this data is gonna be very critical because of unwanted spacing or some other special characters

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the blanks are delimiter like ";" in a .csv, so you can create an Array with String.split(Pattern.quote(" ")); and after every 5th element you jump into the next row.

Try something like that:

```
File f = new File("example.pdf");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        ArrayList<String> Data = new ArrayList<String>();
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] a = line.split(Pattern.quote(" "));
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                if(!(a[i] == null || a[i] == "")) {
                    Data.add(a[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: But the bills can be in different format.so I can't rely on column position

Comment: Mhh, your are right.. But then I thought you need a different algorithm for every different bill

Answer (score 0):

The fact that some values may contain spaces is an issue here, since the values are separated by spaces. If you have control of the program which extracts this information, I would suggest you try escaping the values in its output, eg "Hp laptops". After the input is formatted like this, then normal csv parsing methods should allow you to extract the information mapped to the headers. This lib might help with that:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html